# How to get Goal Conversion history from PIWIK

Tags: matomo, goal-tracking

I am using Piwik managed goal conversion for my pages. How can I get the history of goal conversions like I get the visits history. Currently, I only can fetch the total conversions against an idSite but I need the complete log as well.

I need to fetch this through API.

After some research it turns that `Goals.getConversions` is better option if one just want to gets the conversion for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the [Live! Analytics API](http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/reference/#Live), you should be able to query the visits with conversions, by using the [API Segment parameter](http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/segmentation/#toc-segment-operators) `&segment=visitConverted==1`

This will return all visits with a conversion, then you can grab the conversions from the array for each visit..

Comment: Thanks NickT, I'll give it a try and get back to you. Hopefully the only action I would need to perform after checking the above link is to mark your answer as `accepted` ;o)

Comment: I can get the goals but there is a lot other information which makes the response a bit heavier. Is there a way to fetch the required set of fields only?

Comment: No at present there is no way to only keep a subset of the answer, so you'd have to manually filter it out in your code.